# reading a 1000 Hz (sample freq) signal using 200 Hz sample frequency

Tags: arduino, audio

I wan't to read a signal using my Arduino Pro Micro. The signal is produced from a sound file on my phone, the output from the phone passes through an offset circuit to lift it to be read by the Arduino. My Arduino is set to sample at 200Hz (fixed), but my audio signal has a 1000 Hz sampling frequency. How is reading the 1000 Hz signal using 200 Hz sampling frequency going to affect my data? I've noticed that the time measurement is out of order (1000 samples don't mean 5 secs anymore from the received data from Arduino). Can someone help me understand this point?

My signal's max frequency is 80 Hz, so I think 200 Hz is okay.
My concern is the received sampling frequency. I send the time of the sample with every sample so that I verify the sampling frequency. When I used real sensors with this same Arduino and 200 Hz fs, I got the right fs received, but know it's different. I mean 1000 samples should have 5 seconds worth of data if fs=200 Hz but I got 2.558 seconds. That's what I need to understand.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have major aliasing problems. You generally need to sample at twice the rate of the highest frequency in the signal

Comment: What kind of signal you are generating with your phone?

Comment: Why not just pass the data to the Arduino instead of doing analog conversion in the middle?

Comment: If you can ensure that the signal is band-limited to < 200 Hz (i.e. your signal is between 950-1050 Hz), you can theoretically construct the signal when sampled at 200 Hz. However, that may be more in-depth DSP than you want to get into.

Comment: user2233709 I'm sending heartbeat and breathing signal (for the purpose of simulation),I've been working with real sensor data with this same Arduino and 200Hz freq. The simulator is because we don't have a subject with the needed condition at the moment so we used recorded data. The issue is that the recorded data has 1000 Hz fs

Comment: Scott, because we the Arduino's ADC doesn't take negative voltages, so we lift the signal to make sure that all of it is received.

Comment: uint128 my signal is at most 80 Hz that's why I used 200 Hz (which is also a hardware maximum for arduino)

Comment: "1000 samples should have 5 seconds worth of data if fs=200 Hz but I got 2.558 seconds." - that makes no sense. The Arduino will 'record' the analog signal at whatever sampling rate it is set to. If you record for 5 seconds you _must_ have 5 seconds worth of data! So either it wasn't recording at 200Hz, or some of the data has gone missing.

Comment: Bruce, yes you are right, the current fs isn't 200, I changed my board to an UNO (doesn't use virtual serial communication) and I got perfect readings. I calculated fs from the previous board (pro Micro) and it was alternating between 500 and 333.33 for a while then settling to 200 at the end. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

> How is reading the 1000 Hz signal using 200 Hz sampling frequency going to affect my data?

Unless the bandwidth of the data is really really low compared to the sampling frequency, it is most likely going to destroy the integrity of the data.

As Makato said in the comments, you need to sample at at least twice the frequency of the highest frequency in the signal. So if your 1000 Hz signal has data at 1000 Hz, you need to sample it at at least 2000 Hz.

However, if your audio signal's sampling rate is unneccesarily high - in your case by a factor of 10 compared to the highest data-carrying frequency in the signal - you might be in luck.

See [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) for a less simplified explanation.

Comment: Tbf...  Unless the signal is perfectly band-limited  (ie possible...) You want to sample at 10x. Read Nyquist theorem again

Comment: Yes my frequencies are at most 160 Hz, so 200 is okay. I tried it with real sensor data (breathing and heartbeat) and it was working. But when recorded data is used (we don't have the right subject at the moment) the time vector is now different. I'm sending the time with each sample to make sure that the sampling frequency is correct and to display it. Now 1000 samples should give 5 secs if fs=200 Hz, instead it's 2.558 secs, that's what I'm trying to understand, so I related it to the different original fs

Comment: @Isra your frequencies are at most 160 Hz so **200 is not okay because 200 is not at least twice 160**. It won't work and you won't be able to get it to work.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant 80 Hz, so 160 is (2*80) my max, I'll fix it in the question.